# Add watermark to a video using ffmpeg in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, watermark

I want to add watermark for my video, with ffmpeg i found command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=1500:1000" output.mp4
```

But it run in cli, not in python code(i cannot found). So have anyway to embbeded it to python code(not call in subprocess)?
edit: i found pyffmpeg but no guide to use it too.

Comment: No errors or any other helpful info?

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyffmpeg import FFmpeg
ff = FFmpeg()
ff.options("-i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex overlay=1500:10 output.mp4")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.